connect apex with mysql on oci
I have mysql database located on oci with apex server located on oci too.
I tried to connect apex with my database to create interactive report using rest enabled sql service. I create private endpoint to my database then create connection to this endpoint using oci dbtools, but when setup the connect between apex and my sql database, I got this error connection error
Please can you help me.
thank you.
I want know the reasons of the error and how to solve it.

This error has nothing to do with mysql. You need to check your url configuration as the error message suggests

Can you follow this blog posting to debug your builder session and to get more information about the actual error?
https://diveintoapex.com/2024/04/24/enabling-debug-on-apex-builder/
